How can I properly export a self-hosted bundle in Expo v51 to open it later in Expo Go using a QR code?
Since Expo SDK 49, I've been using expo export --public-url, which outputs a dist folder with android/ios-index.json. I then deployed the dist folder to S3 and generated a QR code pointing to the URL exps://my-host/android-index.json. Everything was working fine; Expo Go successfully opened my build. However, since version 51, I’m encountering the error: "Legacy manifests are no longer supported."
It seems that Expo SDK 51 made changes to how manifest.json is parsed in Expo Go, but unfortunately, I couldn’t find any information about this in the Expo documentation.
What are the new alternatives to expo export --public-url?
I’ve already tried npx expo export, but after hosting it and scanning the QR code, I get the same error: "Legacy manifests are no longer supported."
Thanks in advance for your help!Ï
I want to be able to test my changes in Expo Go before merging and deploying.
